# Identifying ARIMA model from ACF and PACF

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, mathematical-statistics, forecasting, descriptive-statistics

I've identified this as a AR(1) model as the ACF clearly shows a slow decay and the PACF seems like a cut off after lag 2. However, can it also be a ARMA (1,1) model because PACF seems like a damped sinusoid too?

[image: fo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ACF indicates q=[1，2，3，4，5] and PACF indicates p=[1]. I don't think the damping sinusoid shape matters because spikes are almost inside of the significant level.